# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL on Toggle

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am getting this error when I try to use the toggle function.  It might be because of <%=i%> but I'm not sure

```
<% @categorias.each do |categoria| %>
  <%i += 1%>
  <div id = "Categoria" onclick = "$(#<%=i%>).toggle();">
    <b> <%= categoria.categoria_pt %></b>
  </div>
  <% @pratos_precos.each do |pratos_preco| %>
    <% if @pratos.find(pratos_preco.prato_id).categoria_pratos_id.to_s == categoria.id.to_s %>
      <div id = <%=i%> style = "display:none">
        <tr>
          <table class="table-condensed table-bordered" style= "width: 98%">
            <td><%= @pratos.find(pratos_preco.prato_id).nome_pt %></td>
      </div>
```

I get that error when I click on the Category div, but I don't know why.

If I do it like this:

```
<div id = "Categoria" onclick = "$( "#<%=i%>" ).toggle();">
```

I get this error:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<% @categorias.each do |categoria| %>
  <% i += 1 %>
  <div id = "Categoria" onclick = "$('#<%= i %>').toggle();">
    <b><%= categoria.categoria_pt %></b>
  </div>
  <% @pratos_precos.each do |pratos_preco| %>
    <% if @pratos.find(pratos_preco.prato_id).categoria_pratos_id.to_s == categoria.id.to_s %>
      <div id = "<%= i %>" style = "display:none">
        <tr>
        <table class="table-condensed table-bordered" style= "width: 98%">
          <td><%= @pratos.find(pratos_preco.prato_id).nome_pt %></td>
      </div>
```

You'll notice that the `#<%= i %>` section is now surrounded in single quotes to make the resulting jQuery selector valid.  Single quotes are used instead of double quotes, as double quotes are already surrounding the `onclick` handler, which includes the jQuery selector.

Also, the line with `<div id = "<%= i %>" style = "display:none">` now uses double quotes around the id value, as per HTML specs.

With those two changes, it looks like this should work as expected.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! ;)